# How to browse the content of File in window phone 7?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am new to the windows phone 7 development world. I am developing an application in window phone 7. In window mobile application (smart device application) we can browse the content of the mobile device by selecting the tools -> Device Emulator Manager -> slecting the emulator & then after clicking the cradle we can browse the content of the mobile device. I want to know how to do this in windows phone 7 application ? I also want to know how to programatically access the content of the Window Phone 7 ? (for e.g I want to open the screen which we will be  opened after clicking the upload button in asp.net. In that screen we can navigate between the folder structure of the computer. In such way I want to open the screen for window phone 7) Because I am developing an application in which I want the images from the existing mobile device. So I want to browse the content of the mobile device so that I can select the particular image from the existing content of the mobile device & after that I will dynamically add these images to the images folder of my application. Can you please provide me any code or link through which I can resolve the above issue? If anyone know anything that will also help me a lot. Please share anything whatever anyone knows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the security model of Windows Phone 7 and fact that applications are sandboxed means that it is not possible to create a file system browser on the device. You can only see files / the directory structure within IsolatedStorage and you must create these files yourself.

You can, however, use [MediaLibrary.Pictures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary.pictures.aspx) or the [PhotoChooserTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.photochoosertask%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) to access the images stored on the device. These are the images youu'll see in the Pictures hub and, therefore are outside of the files you specifically put in IsolatedStorage.

Comment: Hi Shailesh, Here's a link to an overview on Isolated Storage which Matt mentions if you'd like to check it out. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402541(v=VS.92).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can **only** access the files/directories that are located in the **Isolated Storage** that is assigned to your application, and you can get a list of those via [GetDirectoryNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190297%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) (for folders) and [GetFileNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02ys433%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) (for files). You will have to implement a custom listing mechanism since there is no default storage browser component.